# Mat-Autocomplete options go under the screen on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, angular-material

I'm facing 2 problems with Angular Material Autocomplete component positioned on the bottom of the browser screen.

1. The input field is covered by the keyboard, I found this solution that works but I don't know if it's the correct one for this type of issue

```
    document.getElementById("searchInput").onfocus = () => {
      window.scrollTo(0, window.outerHeight);
      document.body.scrollTop = window.outerHeight;
    }
```

2. The autocomplete options go under the keyboard so the user cannot make a selection.

I tried with Windows 10 + Chrome 73, also with my Android smartphone Xiaomi Mi A1 + Chrome 74 and all works fine, but with IPhone 7 + Chrome 74 I got troubles.

Here you can find the code that I'm using: [Stackblitz - Material autocomplete](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyeusp)